# The skill endpoint is not accepting valid signed requests

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing my own Alexa skill using the Alexa skills Dot Net library (https://github.com/timheuer/alexa-skills-dotnet), Everything worked fine while testing but when I submitted the skill for review I get [This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpoU8.png).

I did some research and found that I needed to verify that the incoming request was coming from Alexa, and that I could do so using the RequestVerification method that is part of the library, and so here's my code:

```
var payload = await req.ReadAsStringAsync();
var skillRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkillRequest>(payload);


Uri signatureCertChainUrl = new Uri(req.Headers["SignatureCertChainUrl"]);
string signature = req.Headers["Signature"];

bool isValid = await RequestVerification.Verify(signature, signatureCertChainUrl, payload);
if (!isValid)
{
   return new BadRequestResult(); 
}
else
{
  //code related to the skill
}
```

I am still getting the error, is there something that I am missing?

This is Amazon's documentation related to the issue: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#cert-verify-signature-certificate-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong!

I had an exception block that did not return a badrequest like so:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    return new BadRequestResult();
}
```

If anyone else has this issue, make sure that all the paths in your code reaches a response that Alexa expects. In my case it kept reaching a part of the code where it expected a 400 error message because of a null exception but got something else, and because of that Alexa assumed that I was not accepting valid signed requests and threw the error.

Hope this helps anyone else who is struggling with this!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your URL validation is **not up to the mark**. Check out [Verify that the request was sent by Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#verify-request-sent-by-alexa). Since, you are not using JavaScript, Java, or Python, you don't have this validation pre-defined in your SDK. Hence, you have to [Manually verify that the request was sent by Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#manually-verify-request-sent-by-alexa).

To manually verify that a request came from the Alexa service, you must write code that performs the following steps:

- Check the request signature to verify the authenticity of the request. Alexa signs all HTTPS requests. For more information, see [Check the request signature](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#check-request-signature).
- Check the request timestamp to make sure that the request is not an old one being sent as part of a replay attack. For more information, see [Check the request timestamp](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#check-request-timestamp).